# Error await keeps creating multiple channels instead of checking

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue where my code is creating more than one channels. The function of the code should:

1. Check to see if the channel exists
2. If Channel does exist don't create a new one.
3. Otherwise, if the channel does not exist create one.

In a nutshell, how it supposed to work, The `on_message` event checks for a response from a user in a direct message sent to the bot, their message is then relayed to a guild channel that either already exists otherwise a new one is created before the message is sent.

In this is the issue is that I can't get around it with a check to see if the channel exists, it sure does but it just duplicates everytime a message is sent:

I have tried both these methods to check:

```
#Check 1

for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.name == f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}" and channel.name is not None:
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)
                else:
                    channel_non = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{message.author.name}{message.author.discriminator}', overwrites=overwrites, category=self.bot.get_channel(744944688271720518))
                await channel_non.send(embed=embed)


#Check 2

 channel_present = False
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.name == f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}":
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)
                    channel_present = True

                if channel_present:
                    channel_non = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{message.author.name}{message.author.discriminator}', overwrites=overwrites, category=self.bot.get_channel(744944688271720518))
                await channel_non.send(embed=embed)
```

The check 2 code causes the `on_message` event to do nothing. Help would be much appreciated I don't know where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would just do it by a command.

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.guild

    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        if channel.name == ctx.message.author:
            await channel.send(embed = embed)
            return
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{ctx.message.author}", overwrites = overwrites, category = self.bot.get_channel(744944688271720518))
    await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `guild = client.get_guild(ctx.guild.id)` you can just say `ctx.guild`, I have submitted an edit please check it.